# How to use scss file in vue js component?

Tags: sass, vuejs2, vue-cli

I have multiple scss file those all imported in another scss file name style.scss. Now i need all the scss compile to css and use all of my components. How it is posible?

I have followed this link [Followed Instruction](https://dev.to/lynnewritescode/my-scss-setup-within-a-vue-cli-3-project-4jan)

Can any one help me please

Comment: check this out, https://medium.com/@mahesh.ks/using-sass-scss-in-vue-js-2-d472af0facf9

Comment: Have you noticed the `patterns` field in the vue.config.js from the tutorial?

Comment: Thank you guys for response :). I have solved this problem following this article https://flaviocopes.com/vue-using-scss/

Answer (score 0):

You can install the following dev dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "node-sass": "^4.1.1",
   "sass-loader": "^3.2.3",
   "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
}
```

And import your scss file inside your App.vue:

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>@import 'style.scss'</style>
```

Comment: Is it copy scss to css file? @Simon

Comment: @ShuvroAkash yes it should import. You can just check your build files after executing `vue-cli-service build`. You can also implement a scss loader as suggested here: https://medium.com/@mahesh.ks/using-sass-scss-in-vue-js-2-d472af0facf9

Comment: The webpack config setting can be found here:
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mahesh-k-s/c8d0df0629d7e9e9d9798ee4d4482184/raw/9dfa6f3f239926fb542f901a640b0530329eb069/webpack.config.js

Comment: Actualy I need to compile scss file and store in a css file that execute in index.html. Is it work for that?

Comment: My project has vue.config.js. There is no webpack file. Then where should i add those setting?

Comment: you can create a webpack.config.js file inside the root directory

Comment: or use the existng vue.config.js and use the `configureWebpack` paramater to configure webpack